# Skip iteration of XML reading loop if exception is met Python

Tags: python, mysql, xml, sorting, lxml

I have a function that reads certain tags out of an XML file. I am trying to make it so that if the tags don't exist (the variable to tag assignment fails) that an exception is called and the file is moved to a different directory and the next file is read in.

Here is my function:

```
def iterateOverXml():
    localPath = "C:\local"
    remotePath = "C:\outbox"
    errorPath = "C:\Error"
    xmlFiles = glob.glob1(localPath,"*.xml")
    for file in xmlFiles:
        print file
        a = os.path.join(localPath,file)
        element = etree.parse(a)


        try:
            data= element.xpath('//Foobar/Data/node()')
            parsedData = [{field.tag: field.text for field in data} for action in data]
            xmlType = parsedData[0]['FormType']
        except:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(localPath,file),errorPath)


        if xmlType == 'record':
            parseTitle(element)
            parseTracks(element)
            parseArtist(element)
            shutil.move(os.path.join(localPath,file),remotePath)
```

**How can I make it so if the exception is met it both moves the file the current iteration is stopped and the next file is called?**

Comment: What do you mean by "skips to the next line"?

Comment: Stops the current iteration and reads the next file.

Comment: By the way, if you want to put a literal `\ ` in a string, you should write it as `\\ `, or use "raw strings" (`r"C:\..."`) since `\ ` is the escape character.

Comment: I thought the same thing but my path "C:\Inbox" works and doesn't error out. Any idea why?

Comment: If the `\ ` is used in an unrecognized sequence, it will be interpreted as a literal `\ `, although this is bad style.  In your example, `\I` is not a known escape sequence, but in `C:\new_files`, `\n` will be replaced with the newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make it so if the exception is met it both moves the file and skips to the next file?

Just use `continue`:

```
for file in xmlFiles:
    # ...

    try:
        # ....
    except:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(localPath,file),errorPath)
        continue  # <---- Will continue at the top of the for loop
                  #       with the next file in xmlFiles
```

Comment: So this will break the current iteration of file and start over?

Comment: It won't start over, it will skip the current iteration and continue with the next one.